# i don't know why this code is writing empty rows on my csv file when using a PC but not on a Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
fieldnames =['quote', 'author']
myFile = open('quotes.csv', 'a')


file = ('quotes.csv')
quoteNum = int(input("How many qoutes do you want to enter: "))

fileEmpty = os.stat(file).st_size == 0

with myFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    if fileEmpty:
        writer.writeheader()
    for entry in range(1,quoteNum + 1 ):
        authur_name = input("Enter the Authors name:")
        quoteValue = input("Enter the Qoute by "+authur_name + " here: " )
        writer.writerow({'author': authur_name, 'quote': quoteValue})
```

Comment: Perhaps its because the two OS's have different line terminators?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so before posting your next question here. A title and a code dump isn't really appropriate; the body of your question should contain a clear problem description as well, and *I don't know why* isn't really a question.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the newline character when you open the file.  On Windows, the default ends up adding an extra `'\r'`.

```
with open('quotes.csv', 'a', newline='\n') as myFile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    ...
```

Comment: According to the [`csv` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3), `newline=''` allows `csv` to do it's internal newline handling correctly.

Answer (score 4):

The python csv module does it's own universal newline handling, so from the python documentation you open file objects in the following two ways.

On [Python 2.7.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) you need to open files using the 'b' flag

```
myFile = open('quotes.csv', 'ab')
```

On [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.writer) you need to pass the newline option

```
myFile = open('quotes.csv', 'a', newline='')
```

Some systems are affected by this (windows) and some aren't, as you have seen.

Comment: Nicely done. It could be improved by turning *python documentation* into a link. Better yet, turn the *Python xx* references into links to the appropriate documentation.

Comment: Yes @Ken, totally should have done that. Added in now.

Comment: Excellent! I wish I could upvote twice. :-) You'll get the extra votes from others that see the effort, though. Thanks!